# Поправить запрос MysQL

Tags: php, mysql

Помогите, пожалуйста, подправить запрос. Нужно, чтобы на выходе был случайный вывод новостей, а не по порядку (допустим новостей 10 и каждый раз должно выводить какие-то разные 3 из них). Здесь где-то нужно применить rand(), но не знаю где.

```
public function getListIndex($limit = 3)
{
    $sql = "SELECT a.*, cc.category_name FROM news AS a ";
    $sql .= " LEFT JOIN category cc ON cc.id_category = a.id_category ";
    $sql .= " WHERE a.is_published = 1 AND is_analitic = 0 AND a.id_news IN (SELECT id_news FROM news AS b ";
    $sql .= " WHERE b.is_published = 1 AND is_analitic = 0 AND b.id_category = a.id_category AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM news AS c WHERE c.is_published = 1 AND is_analitic = 0 AND c.id_news >= b.id_news AND c.id_category = b.id_category) <= {$limit}) ";
    $sql .= " ORDER BY a.id_category";

    return $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

Comment: ну давайте подумаем вместе, что у нас отвечает за сортировку? Куда же поставить функцию RAND()?

Comment: если сделать ORDER BY rand(), a.id_category, то не работает

Comment: и в конце после {limit}, если поставить ORDER BY rand() тоже нет

Comment: Ну как это не работает. С чего вы взяли, что не работает? Прекрасно себе работает. Может у вас проблемы с вашими сложными конструкциями и адскими подзапросами? Кстати, зачем они?

Comment: когда вставляю в том месте, то оно просто выбирает 3 новости и меняет их местами, а не каждый раз новые вставляет

Comment: ну так потому что вы указали лимит в подзапросе, а не основном

Comment: попробовал указать в основном, всё равно не получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не вдаваясь в вопрос организации кода и использовании PDO и подстановкой параметров, только помощь в SQL. Функцию RAND() нужно добавить в конструкцию `ORDER BY`. А что бы лимит был корректным, то делаем его в основном запросе. Да и вообще убираем лишние подзапросы.

```
public function getListIndex($limit = 3)
{
    $sql = "SELECT a.*, cc.category_name FROM news AS a ";
    $sql .= "LEFT JOIN category cc ON cc.id_category = a.id_category ";
    $sql .= "WHERE a.is_published = 1 AND is_analitic = 0 ";
    $sql .= "ORDER BY RAND(), a.id_category LIMIT {$limit}";

    return $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

Comment: спасибо, но теперь категории на странице не зафиксированы, а меняются местами)

Comment: и категории вывело 3 из 6, а выводило раньше все 6

Comment: @KvinT как озвучили вопрос, так и получили ответ. Тут не клуб парного программирование или фриланс биржа. Если правильно понял про категорию, то поменяйте местами `RAND()` и `a.id_category`

Comment: @KvinT перечетайте свой вопрос

Comment: оно помогло, но теперь вывело 1 категорию только, спасибо за помощь, буду разбираться в чем проблема

Comment: @KvinT у вас в самой формулировке проблема – вам нужно случайные 3 статьи, а теперь вы говорите, что должно быть 6 категорий. Но 3 статьи это априори меньше 6-ти. Сформулируйте сначала четко для себя задачу, а потом перепишите код. И не бойтесь сделать несколько запросов

Comment: на главной странице должно быть 6 категорий и в каждой из них 3 рандомные новости. ваш запрос работает (оно выбирает 3 рандомные новости), но теперь отображается только 1 категория со своими 3-мя новостями. в моём запросе отображались все 6 категорий и в каждой из них было по 3 новости, но новости не были рандомными, а 3 фиксированные отображались и менялись простом местами при перезагрузке